# Como puedo sacar un elemento de una lista en Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Por ejemplo si yo tengo la lista [1,2,3,4,5,6,5,3,4] y yo quiero sacar UN 5, no todos. Como deberia hacerlo? En mi caso:

```
sacoBolita :: [Bolitas] -> Bolitas -> [Bolitas]
```

En este caso, yo tengo una lista de Bolitas, y recibo la bolita que quiero sacar. Si en la lista no tengo ninguna bolita para sacar da error, pero si la hay tendria que sacar una sola

Comment: No tengo claro si lo pides es una función de filtro (`filter`), normal y corriente, y que tienes disponible en haskell por defecto. En la lista de ejemplo tienes dos 5. ¿El resultado final ha de ser una lista con los dos 5 (`[5,5]`) o sólo una lista con un 5 (`[5]`)? Por cierto, en programación funcional los errores tienen otra dinámica. Si has definido tu función para devolver listas, entonces un fallo debería devolver una lista, en este caso la lista vacía.

Comment: @ChemaCortes la idea es devolver una lista que sea igual pero con un cinco menos ([1,2,3,4,5,6,3,4]), aunque ya encontre la solucion mediante el uso de una funcion de Data.List, deleteBy

Comment: Entiendo. ¿Y cómo pensabas tratar el error de no encontrar la bolita buscada? Es común retornar la lista encapsulada como `Maybe [Bolitas]`, pero no sé si es lo que buscas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varias formas de hacerlo. Lo primero que se me vino a la mente fue usar un HashSet, aunque es ligeramente más complicado y esa solución siento que está más del lado imperativo que del funcional.

Como sea, la solución más sencilla y "puritana", hablando de programación funcional, que se me ocurrió es la siguiente:

```hs
sacoBolita :: [Int] -> Int -> [Int]

sacoBolita [] e = []
sacoBolita (x:xs) e = if x == e then xs else x:(sacoBolita xs e)
```

Básicamente usamos pattern matching y recursividad para eliminar (realmente construimos una nueva lista) únicamente el primer elemento en la lista `x:xs` que sea igual a `e`. Para clarificar aún más:

1. Si `x == e` se regresa la lista pero SIN el elemento `x`. A esta lista retornada será agregada el resto de elementos `x` provenientes de llamadas anteriores a `sacoBolita` (que justamente se hace en el `else`) o si no hay más llamadas, simplemente se retorna la lista y listo :)
2. Si `x /= e` sabemos entonces que `x` debe existir en la lista que retornemos por lo que el resultado debe ser `[x, restoDeElementos...]` (o en hs `x:restoDeElementos`), y para saber cuál es el resto de elementos simplemente hacemos recursividad. Nótese que no retornamos `[x, xs...]` (o `x:xs`) porque no sabemos aún si existe algún `x` dentro de `xs` que satisfaga `x == e` (de ahí la necesidad de recursividad).

Por último, el comportamiento asintótico del algoritmo antes descrito es `O(n)`.